# Select language when opening a file (excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I recently had problems letting users change the language while using the file.
I was hoping there was a way to make them choose the language (English or French) only when they open the file. I imagine it like an installer where a window pops up in front of the user. He then chooses the language using a drop-down list and then clicks 'Ok'. The file would open and be in English or French depending on his selection.

If anything like that is possible, please let me know how.
I'm open to suggestions if it's not possible or if they're is a better way to open the file and make the user choose the language they want.

Thank you.

EDIT: The file in question is an Excel file.

Comment: I guess you are referring to some kind of translation within your Excel file. In that case you can make use of the `Workbook_Open` event to show that windows you are talking about in your question. But note that this will only work if VBA macros are enabled (which is not the case in some companies).

Comment: @Ralph
Oh I did not know that.
And do I only use the 'Open' part of the Workbook to make the user choose between the 2 languages?
Or does it only make the window appear and then I need to code in another section of the Workbook to make the choices appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to Microsoft Excel Objects in your VBA Project tree. Under Microsoft Excel Objects should be an object called "ThisWorkbook". View the code for this object and at the top of the window will be two dropdown menus. Select "Workbook" in the left one and "Open" in the right one.

This will create a Private Sub called Workbook_Open() that will execute every time the workbook is opened. From here you can call a userform that disaplays your language options. You can also insert a button in your workbook that can point towards Workbook_Open() so users can switch languages without having to close and reopen the file.

Comment: Thanks!
Now I only need to link my drop-down list to my language and I'm all good!